# How to input a JSON byteCode (txt file) and parse it?

Tags: json, input, inputstream

I made a JSON file and the I used FileOutputStream to save it as a text file in my hard drive . Then I use FileinputStream to input the file in a separated class. I use this code to print the JSON , but how can i parse it now using JSONParser .

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("D:\\XmlToJson.txt");
    ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
    JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) objectInputStream.readObject();
```

Comment: Although one can guess the programming language here being Java, it would be nice if you add a tag stating the language.

Answer (score 0):

`ObjectInputStream` is not the correct class to use here. That is to read Java objects from Java's own serialisation scheme. Has nothing to do with JSON. And why `JSONParser` if you don't want to parse lazy and use the parse events to build some data structure other than a `JSONArray` then a [`JsonReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonReader.html) is the way to go.

Slightly adapted example from the Java documentation:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("D:\\XmlToJson.txt");
    JsonReader jsonReader = Json.createReader(fileInputStream);
    JsonArray array = jsonReader.readArray();
    jsonReader.close();
    // ...
}
```